# Rails 3 app, some controllers render blank white screens only in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, production-environment

I have a rails 3.0.7 application with devise authentication that works great in development mode, but certain actions render blank pages in production mode. No error messages, no view gets rendered at all. In fact, no controller code is executed for the problematic pages. 
For example, when I try to submit an event through the event controller's create method, the server logs show:

```
Started POST "/events" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-06-01 17:27:03 -0500
Processing by EventsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"Pyer5ld7aRZpklf7c7lfq8sYefDW1euO/lGY6r7LlOc=", "event"=> {"date"=>"2011-06-08", "address"=>"Aladdin Theatre, Portland, OR "}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
Completed in 30ms
```

But nothing gets saved in the database, and no view gets rendered. I get redirected to a completely blank page. This only happens in production mode.

Comment: You might want to try setting your logging level to `debug` and rebooting.

Comment: posting code from the controllers / actions that are generating the white pages would also be helpful

Comment: did you ever find a cause for this? Seeing the same thing...